# kendo grid - fillter row based on column filter option

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I am using kedoGrid. In the link I provided here, its is working fine. But the issue is its not updating the table based on multi-check option.

[official link](http://dojo.telerik.com/).

with available functionality I am able to filter based on checked value. but its not updating when I uncheck and click on filter button.

Table will get update only if we click clear button. Since new to kendo grid I am finding some difficulties to apply Jquery to update the table.

trying to convert it in jquery but failed. would be better if some share jsfiddle/plunker link

I am trying to achieve this in kendo Grid [so far][2]

many thanks for any help.

```
  [1]: http://dojo.telerik.com/
  [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/vy384myy/2/
```

Comment: You forgot to attach jQuery as an external resource in your jsfiddle. Adding it fixes your problem.

Comment: @JayGould i updated the fiddle thanks for mentioned it.. but the thing is how to achieve that in kendo grid. its not when uncheck the checked value and click on filter button in kendogrid